# Select from multiple tables with results labeled by table

Tags: mysql, join, select

Is there any method for doing a MySQL multi-table select that can tag/label the columns from the table the column originated from?

```
table1
tID   name    desc
---------------------
1    foo     lots of foo
2    bar     lots of bar
3    foobar  none of these

table2
oID   tID    orderNo
------------------------
1    1       19001
2    1       19002
3    3       19004
4    2       19005

SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 WHERE t1.tID=t2.tID ;
```

The output would be:

```
tID    name    desc            oID      orderNo
-----------------------------------------------
1      foo     lots of foo      1       19001
1      foo     lots of foo      1       19002
2      foo     lots of bar      4       19005
3      foo     none of these    3       19004
```

But I am looking for something that would output like the following:

```
t1.tID    t1.name    t1.desc            t2.oID      t2.orderNo
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         foo        lots of foo        1           19001
1         foo        lots of foo        1           19002
2         foo        lots of bar        4           19005
3         foo        none of these      3           19004
```

This small example represents a bigger issue I am trying to tackle.  It would allow for one query but also be able to tell me which table the data came from when parsing the data.

Comment: You need aliases for each column

Comment: Simply *join* your tables using meaningful *aliases* and select and alias the required columns from each.

Comment: there is no Oid in tbale 2 and t1 has no name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases for each column and I suggest writing a proper join.

```
SELECT t1.tID as `t1.tID`,   
       t1.name as `t1.name`,   
       t1.desc as  `t1.desc`,  
       t2.oID  as `t2.oID`, 
       t2.orderNo  as `t2.orderNo`
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 on  t1.tID=t2.tID ;
```

Comment: @rolinger You can't use `*` with an alias. Aliases can be used for individual columns. You'll have to alias each column instead.. Read more on : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html